# regression coefficient NA in r

Tags: r, regression

```
Call:
lm(formula = y_diff ~ y_mean + math_mean + math_diff + history_mean + 
    history_diff:math_diff, data = dat3)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.2202 -0.9279  0.0280  0.9511  4.0430 

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)            -0.000719   0.044265  -0.016    0.987    
y_mean                 -0.002668   0.037504  -0.071    0.943    
math_mean               0.008540   0.054655   0.156    0.876    
math_diff               1.020913   0.030885  33.055   <2e-16 ***
history_mean                  NA         NA      NA       NA    
math_diff:history_diff  0.002409   0.022277   0.108    0.914    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.396 on 993 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5253,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5234 
F-statistic: 274.7 on 4 and 993 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I've got the results like this.
I think it indicates history_mean covaries with other variable or so.

so I've looked correlation matrix

```
                      y_diff      y_mean    math_mean   math_diff  history_mean  history_diff
y_diff            1.00000000 0.019690192 -0.018111710  0.72476685  0.0467031520  0.7041651149
y_mean            0.01969019 1.000000000  0.726906933  0.02515257  0.7280406855  0.0026510387
math_mean        -0.01811171 0.726906933  1.000000000 -0.02976788  0.0584370084  0.0043956974
math_diff         0.72476685 0.025152574 -0.029767875  1.00000000  0.0662794437  0.0211446580
history_mean      0.04670315 0.728040686  0.058437008  0.06627944  1.0000000000 -0.0005342539
history_diff      0.70416511 0.002651039  0.004395697  0.02114466 -0.0005342539  1.0000000000
diff_interaction -0.02028478 0.040635264  0.055462119 -0.03149922  0.0037054390  0.0030266452

                 diff_interaction
y_diff               -0.020284784
y_mean                0.040635264
math_mean             0.055462119
math_diff            -0.031499222
history_mean          0.003705439
history_diff          0.003026645
diff_interaction      1.000000000
```

history_mean only has a 0.73 correlation with y_mean.
it seems high, but
math_mean also has a 0.73 correlation but it is not NA in the regression results.
so, I was wondering.

Comment: In the regression output notice `Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)`. Did you obtain `history_mean` from a combination of two or more variables?

Comment: You seem to have perfect multicollinearitry. [Check for aliases](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/alias) and maybe also check variance inflation factors.

Comment: @user2974951 No, but I combined math_mean and history_mean to make a y_mean. not technically combined but it is similar to combining each other.

Comment: @Roland Yes, this is not my actual data,  this is simulated data. I intended to make partially overlapped variable, but really don't know why only history_mean is NA, rather than math_mean is NA

Comment: There is only one row of NAs because only one predictor needs to be removed so that the remaining predictors are linearly independent.